# How to add persistent buttons to a Navigation Drawer?

Tags: java, android, sdk

I want to replicate the Navigation Drawer similar to that of the LinkedIn App below:

[image]

Note that the message, notification, and the settings buttons at the top are persistent and are not part of the scrollable list.

I've followed the official Android tutorial for Navigation Drawer as well as numerous other tutorials that simply do not provide additional light into how I can achieve this.

The best I could think of was to add 3 ImageButtons to the header layout of the Navigation Drawer template in Android Studio 2.1.1.

**EDIT**: As per Prat's and a few others advice, I've included an additional header layout just before the drawer that contains the 3 buttons, but no matter the z-ordering of the layouts within the xml, it seems to hide behind the drawer. See image illustration below:

[image]
[image]

Below are the layout files:

header.xml (contains the 3 buttons)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="right"
    android:background="#111">

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/imageButton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_menu_manage" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/imageButton3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_menu_manage" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/imageButton2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_menu_manage" />
</LinearLayout>
```

nav_header_main.xml (default generated header)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="right"
    android:background="#111">

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/imageButton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_menu_manage" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/imageButton3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_menu_manage" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/imageButton2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_menu_manage" />
</LinearLayout>
```

activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:openDrawer="start">

    <include
        layout="@layout/app_bar_main"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:background="#fff">


        <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
            android:id="@+id/nav_view"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="start"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="false"
            app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_main"
            app:menu="@menu/activity_main_drawer" />

        <include
            android:id="@+id/header"
            layout="@layout/header"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true" />

    </RelativeLayout>
</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Comment: Try <navigationview>.In that you can define those buttons in headerlayout

Comment: Put your `Button`s above the `NavigationView` inside another `ViewGroup` that you use as the drawer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to do like this :

**header.xml**(top most layout where you have 3 images)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal">

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/imageButton"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_menu_manage" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/imageButton3"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_menu_manage" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/imageButton2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_menu_manage" />
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

**nav_header_main**( default android header)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/nav_header_height"
    android:background="@drawable/side_nav_bar"
    android:gravity="bottom"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark">
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/nav_header_vertical_spacing"
        android:src="@android:drawable/sym_def_app_icon" />
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/nav_header_vertical_spacing"
        android:text="Android Studio"
        android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Body1" />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="android.studio@android.com" />
</LinearLayout>
```

then finally the **main layout** showing

1. header(top)
2. nav_main_header
3. listview

```
<!-- The main content view -->
<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/flFragmentContainer"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />

<!-- The navigation drawer -->
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="240dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:background="#111">

    <include android:id="@+id/header"
        layout="@layout/header"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_height="100dp"/>

    <include android:id="@+id/header2"
        layout="@layout/nav_header_main"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_below="@id/header"
        android:layout_height="100dp"/>

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/lvDrawer"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
        android:layout_below="@id/header2"
        android:divider="@android:color/transparent"
        android:dividerHeight="0dp" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Thanks, this is a good stepping stone, but while I tried to do what you advise, the buttons seems to always be behind the drawer layout. Please note that I'm using the newest template in Android Studio 2.1 which employs NavigationView as the Drawer. I've updated the question to reflect this difficulty. Hopefully you might know the answer...

Comment: Playing around with the relativelayout, I was able to fix this problem, thank you, I will update this as solved :)

Answer (score 0):

Use `recyclerview` with adapter for this. You can implement any structure of custom views for items.